# Java: How can I load files using Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

can anyone help me with this? I am trying to load all my text documents in a folder using scanner. However, it seems that the scanner only output the names of my text documents!

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class FileDemo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    final File f1=new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dataFiles/");
    String filename="";



    for(final File fileEntry:f1.listFiles()){

        filename=fileEntry.getName();
     Scanner input=new Scanner(f1+"\\"+filename);
     String data = " "; //reset String data when new files are loaded


            while(input.hasNext()){

              data += input.next();
              input.useDelimiter("\t"); 


            }

           System.out.println(data);  


    }

  }


   }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Scanner(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) javadoc. It explains perfectly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a `Scanner` with a `String` will make the `Scanner` read the contents of the `String`, as specified in [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-):

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.

You need to pass a `File` to the `Scanner` constructor, as noted by [`Scanner(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) to read the contents of the file:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(fileEntry);
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a File Object instead of String.

So You need to replace

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(f1+"\\"+filename);
```

with

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(fileEntry);
```

Comment: `File fileEntry` is the `File` you want/need.